# Set cellattr function dynamically in JQGrid is not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid in my application. I am preparing Meta data dynamically for each column.
When I am setting `cellattr:"functionname”` for any of the column is not working.
Because I am setting this in double quotes, so it's not working. So is there any workaround of this problem.
I am loading data from array.

Please let me know any suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? The required functionality exists only in jqGrid 4.7 or in free jqGrid 4.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jqGrid 4.7.x or [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.8.x (it's my fork of jqGrid) then you do can use string as the value of `cellattr`. To define "mapping" between the "name" of `cellattr` (the string value) like `cellattr: "myCellAttr"` and the function implementation you can use

```
$.jgrid.cellattr = $.jgrid.cellattr || {};
$.extend($.jgrid.cellattr, {
    myCellAttr: function (rowId, value, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        ...
    }
});
```

See [my post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/allow-to-use-strings-as-values-of-cellattr-and-rowattr) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellattrAndRowAttrAsString.htm) and [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631) which was merged to the code of jqGrid 4.7.

Comment: @PavanTiwari: One common remark which is not related to my answer. You have right to vote up to 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)), but you don't use the right. The problem is that voting will be used as one of the main criteria by searching engine of stackoverflow and even by google which use stackoverflow specific searching criteria. So the answers/questions with low vote will be almost not found by searching. If you vote any helpful answer or question which you find **you help in the way other users to find the information**.